# Ошибка: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-программирование, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe'
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,executable_path=r'C:/Users\user\Desktop\Win_99992_chrome-win32.test_chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.python.org")
```

Ошибка:

```
DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,executable_path=r'C:/Users\user\Desktop\Win_99992_chrome-win32.test_chromedriver.exe')
```

Но Canary обновлен до последней версии. Как решить?

Comment: Здравствуй. Вместо chrome_options = options введи options = options.

Comment: не тот слеш? (C:\Users\user\Desktop\...)

Comment: @Jack_oS, в винде направление слешей не имеет значения. Кроме автокомплита в консоли.

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка в трейсе не говорит об устаревшей версии, **DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options** - про то, что **chrome_options** устарел, и вам нужно использовать **options**.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe', options=options)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь ошибки нет, но браузер по- прежнему открывается, почему не работает безглавый режим?

Comment: @6APAIII попробуйте обновить драйвер: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: Canary Chrome driver, обычный не годится , так?

Comment: @6APAIII если не нужен --headless, то - годится, вполне )) но если нужен, то его ядро должно быть на версии выше ChromeDriver 79